# Jquery Autocomplete issue with Json data

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a function that returns the Json data below. It changes every time a value is selected in a drop down list.

```
[
    {"Code":"1","Name":"Name1","City":"City1"},
    {"Code":"2","Name":"Name2","City":"City2"},
    {"Code":"2","Name":"Name3","City":"City3"},
    {"Code":"3","Name":"Name4","City":"City4"}
]
```

This is the Jquery used to get the Json data.

```
    function GetDataByState() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            data: { ID: myValue },
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dataListByState = data;
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my autocomplete code. My question is how can I transform the Json data to make it work?

```
        $('#SectionName').autocomplete({
            source: dataListByState 
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#code").val(code value from dataListByState);
                $("#city").val(city value from dataListByState);
            }
        });
```

Thank you.

Comment: In order to help, you need to explain how you want **three columns of data** to be represented in a single autocomplete.

Comment: I want the name to show up as autocomplete and in the select function set the code and city value from associated with the selected name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this answer [jquery-ui autocomplete, manipulate json & javascript to parse to hidden input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274834/jquery-ui-autocomplete-manipulate-json-javascript-to-parse-to-hidden-input-fi?rq=1][1]) I was able to figure it out. I just needed to change the Name for Value in the function that returns the Json data. Now my json data looks like this:

```
[
{"Value":"Name1", "Code":"1","City":"City1"},
{"Value":"Name2", "Code":"2","City":"City2"},
{"Value":"Name3", "Code":"3","City":"City3"},
{"Value":"Name4", "Code":"4","City":"City4"}
]
```